# Add ; to end of line + next line Sublime Text key binding

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, key-bindings

I would like to know how I could create a key binding to say CMD + ;  which will add a ; at the end of the line and then move the next line.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a macro `eol_semi.sublime-macro`

```
[
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} },
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": ";"}},
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n"}}
]
```

then add a keybinding to it in your user `.sublime-keymap` file

```
{ "keys": ["super+;"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/Snippets/test_snippets/eol_semi.sublime-macro"} }
```